# Change MainPage from Content page in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin. How do I change MainPage from ContentPage. Initially when my App load my MainPage is the LoginPage then after I logged in I want my Master page to be my MainPage. How do I do that?
Curretly I am using navigation.Pushmodalasync it works but I have a different requirement that I need to set my MainPage.

```
await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Master());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just reassign it

```
App.Current.MainPage = new MyPage();
```